# SSRS Expression - Sum based on condition, unable to get it to return zero if sum returns null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am creating an expression in SSRS that calculates the number of days where the conditions are met.

The Expression I am currently using:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!Charge.Value = "Chargeable" AND Fields!Progress.Value = "Booked", Fields!Number_of_Days.Value, Nothing), "DataSet1")
```

> I have tried using some suggestions such as 'IsNothing' but trying to
>   copy the same sort of formatting as other answers has given me a
>   "#ERROR" when the report is run.

But, this could be because I did the formatting wrong when attempting this.

**Cover Page Design View:**

[image: Cover Page Design]

**Running The Report:**

[image: Report Run]

As you can see, the values that are coming up are 100% correct - have double checked. Just want zeros to show instead of blanks. The reason there are zeros showing up in the screenshot is because in the the data displayed below this (actual report) has zeros showing up for the number of days column. I cannot show this data as it is sensitive.

I need to use the exact same expression, but be able to display zero if it returns null or zero.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: =Sum(
IIF(Fields!Charge.Value = "Chargeable" AND Fields!Progress.Value = "Booked", Fields!Number_of_Days.Value, 0)
, "DataSet1")

shall this not work?

Also does your Number_of_Days is either integer or decimal and not Date?

Comment: Changing the Nothing to 0 gives #Error on run. (I thought the exact same thing too)

Comment: Number of days is a decimal

Comment: can you post screenshot of your dataset i.e what data is coming into ssrs.
Also screenshot of your Report in design mode where you are using this function, seems like out of scope or something issue

Comment: Have added my dataset above. Will try and get you a screenshot in a moment.

Comment: @AnkUser I have added both now, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Screenshot of dataset (I mean actual data) rather than code.
Also could we try at first step, just field Fields!Number_of_Days.Value rather than any sum or calculation and then move step by step

Comment: Have changed some screenshots, let me know if you still need to see more - at this point though, the screenshots are with the expression I originally posted. The values which are displaying are 100% correct, I just need the others to return as zero if they are zero

Comment: Worth noting - as I realised that the data actually looks super confusing as there are zeros returning: the database can store zeros for the number of days, normally for proposed days/non-chargeable days this is entered in as zero for the number of days column, can be changed later on if needed. Below this in the report is all the data that makes this data, but is too sensitive to share.

Comment: Alright so you have all the data coming correct, it is only when you set manually to 0.
Could you please check what type of your Text box which will hold this data in SSRS (where you are setting expression)? Is it default or Number.

Comment: All the Text Boxes on the cover page are numbers, 2 decimal places.

Comment: ewww strange!! you probably tried setting this textbox as plain 0.
If not try setting 0 manually

Comment: At this point, I am considering just doing all of the calculations in separate database columns! Seems like such an easy thing to do, have tried pretty much every suggestion I could find to work around this - tried defaulting zero but expression overrides it and just nulls the zero

Comment: Since you're adding decimal numbers, you should convert your `0` to decimal with `CDEC(0)` to make the SUM work. Your error message was probably about the mixed types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary fix that should work:

```
=ROUND(Sum( IIF(Fields!Charge.Value = "Chargeable" AND Fields!Progress.Value = "Booked", Fields!Number_of_Days.Value, Nothing) , "DataSet1"), 2)
```

I don't know how this will affect the data, but it's a nice workaround and will get it to display 0.00.

Comment: Yooo! This did it. I'm gonna use this and mark this as the answer - Will test to see if this affects the data and let you know - THANK YOU!

Comment: Since it's SUMming (and not COUNTing), you should use 0 instead of NOTHING. Since they are decimals, use `CDEC(0)` to avoid the type error.